# Database.com update with REST api

Tags: database.com

I am trying to use the Database.com REST API to update a record in my database.

Using the REST explorer in my workbench it always gives me an HTTP error (400 bad request) + some HTML that says: We are down for maintenance. Sorry for the inconvenience. We'll be back shortly.

I also get the same error using other REST clients.

The odd thing is that it is only occurring with the update method. GET and Query work perfectly...

What I have in the rest explorer: (I left out my ID numbers)
**Methodurl:** /services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Album__c/{albumid}

**Request headers:**
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json

**Request body:**
{"Name":"Schoppen aas"}

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: This happens rarely and i have experienced the same and you may need to wait for some time and you will be able to acess the workbench

Comment: I am able to access the workbench!! I can even execute most of the REST methods. But I can not execute that PATCH method, in the response I get an HTML page that says it's down for maintenace...

Comment: Thanks for making me understand the actual problems .Certainly this will be bug in workbench #safeharbour .Need to look more on cause.

Comment: Yes it is possible that it is a bug, but I also get the same response from my own application or an external REST client so it is also possible that I'm doing something wrong. But I cannot find what it is...

Comment: Which HTTP method are you using for the update? Are you including an OAuth token in the request? Do you see the same behavior with a standard object such as Account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a bug with the database.com inbound proxy where it was incorrectly rejecting PATCH requests. Previously, you had to use the _HttpMethod parameter with a POST request to have your request go through, e.g.

```
POST /services/data/v26.0/sobjects/Album__c/{albumid}?_HttpMethod=PATCH
```

Fortunately, this issue is now fixed as of 2012-12-12. PATCH requests may now be used in Database.com organizations.

Answer (score 2):

I'll be honest - I have not tried PATCH with workbench.  Have you tried using the POST w/ Patch Override?  From the docs:

'If you use an HTTP library that doesn't allow overriding or setting an arbitrary HTTP method name, you can send a POST request and provide an override to the HTTP method via the query string parameter _HttpMethod. In the PATCH example, you can replace the PostMethod line with one that doesn't use override:

PostMethod m = new PostMethod(url + "?_HttpMethod=PATCH");'